# CALayer (CAAnimation) animatable property drawing bug

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, calayer, caanimation

I'm creating bar charts, with bar animation. I draw them in a views underline layer (which is my custom `BarChartLayer`). This layer is responsible for all the drawings.

For animating chart bars I use animatable property named `procentAnimation`. During the animatable change of this value, in draw method, I calculate steps between values of two arrays (`oldValues`, `newValues`).

The first animation from oldValues to newValues works well. After animation in animation delegate I swapping the values of the two arrays.

The second animation should look like reverse animation. But after animation starts bars jumps to the first animation begin position and then animation continuous as like first animation, after completion chart bars jumps back to final position of second animation.

In debug mode I find that, in moment when I add the second animation the values of properties `oldValues` and `newValues` stay correct, but when animation begins in method `draw(in:)` the values of `oldValues` and `newValues` jump back to what the are were being during the first animation.

Is it a bug or is there some mechanism that I don't understand? How to work around this?

```
class BarChartLayer: CALayer {

    var oldValues: [CGFloat] = [45, 34, 12, 88, 17, 77, 88, 10] {
        didSet {
            debugPrint("oldValues set")
        }
    }
    var newValues: [CGFloat] = [92, 72, 64, 32, 28, 15, 11, 33] {
        didSet {
            debugPrint("newValues set")
        }
    }

    var numberOfBars: CGFloat = 8
    var space: CGFloat = 10

    @objc var procentAnimation : CGFloat = 0
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == #keyPath(procentAnimation) {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey:key)
    }

    func animateBarsChange() {
        let ba = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:#keyPath(BarChartLayer.procentAnimation))
        procentAnimation = 100
        ba.duration = 4.0
        ba.fromValue = 0
        ba.delegate = self
        add(ba, forKey:nil)
    }

    func barWidth(rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        return (rect.width - CGFloat(space * (numberOfBars - 1))) / CGFloat(numberOfBars)
    }

    func procentRanndomizer(rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.random(in: 1...100) * rect.height / 100
    }

    func makeProcentFor(value: CGFloat, rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        return value * rect.height / 100
    }

    func additionalHeight(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return (newValues[index] - oldValues[index]) / 100
    }

    func makeRandomArr() -> [CGFloat] {
        var arr = [CGFloat]()
        for _ in 0..<8 {
            arr.append(CGFloat.random(in: 1...100))
        }
        return arr
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        let con = ctx
        let rect = self.bounds

        con.addRect(rect)
        con.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)
        con.fillPath()

        var px:CGFloat = 0
        let bw = barWidth(rect: rect)

        debugPrint("OLD - \(oldValues)")
        debugPrint("NEW - \(newValues)")

        let oldValues = self.oldValues

        for i in 0..<Int(numberOfBars) {
            px = CGFloat(i) * (bw + space)
            let h = oldValues[i] + procentAnimation * additionalHeight(index: i)
            con.addRect(CGRect(x: px, y: 0, width: bw, height: makeProcentFor(value: h, rect: rect)))
        }

        con.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        con.fillPath()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}

extension BarChartLayer: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            let temp = self.oldValues
            self.oldValues = self.newValues
            self.newValues = temp//makeRandomArr()
            self.procentAnimation = 0
            debugPrint("------------------------------------")
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mark custom animatable properties with `@NSManaged` because Core Animation creates copies of your model layer for rendering. `@NSManaged` disallows default values. So you should override `defaultValue(forKey:)` instead.

```
@NSManaged var procentAnimation : CGFloat

override class func defaultValue(forKey inKey: String) -> Any? {
    return inKey == "procentAnimation" ? 0.0 : super.defaultValue(forKey: inKey)
}
```

You also shouldn't use UIKit functions inside of CALayer implementations. So you should replace `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext` with their Core Graphics counterparts:

```
override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
    ctx.saveGState()
    ...
    ctx.restoreGState()
}
```